# How to Model 1-to-zero-or-one in Code First

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

An individual can have a "progam id code" assigned to them, but that code can be reassigned to someone else, but this code can never be assigned to more than one person. Also, it is not required to have a program id assigned.

This sounds like a 1-to-zero-or-one - how do I code this in a Code First Approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you a One to One/One to Zero relationship

```
public class User
{
  public int ID { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public virtual Program Program { set;get;}
}

public class Program
{
  public int ID { set;get;}
  public string ProgramName {set;get;}
}
```

That will give you a table like this where You can have a one to One/ Zero relation ship

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to set anything in the OnModelCreating method in my DBContext class?

Comment: @Erik: Not needed. You don't need to do anything with fluent API if you follow the default (naming) conventions EFcodefirst is looking for. See my updated answer